# Jolt transformer adding current time in long format

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Need help with inserting the current date/time in long value using Jolt.

I want the new filed to be inserted for each list element with the current time.

**`"extracted_at" : ${now()}`** --> Not working

**Input Json**

```json
{
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "action": "create",
      "actor": {
        "type": "user"
      },
      "audit": {
        "timestamp": 1568677280
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "action": "update",
      "actor": {
        "type": "user"
      },
      "audit": {
        "timestamp": 1568677280
      }
    }
  ],
  "response_metadata": {
    "next_cursor": "hmV4dF9jcXJzb3I6MTU3OTg1NTC1jMWFFDGVmZGQwOTU="
  }
}
```

**Output Json**

```json
{
  "list": [
    {
      "extracted_at" : 1668677280,
      "id": "1",
      "action": "create",
      "actor": {
        "type": "user"
      },
      "audit": {
        "timestamp": 1568677280
      }
    },
    {
      "extracted_at" : 1668677280,
      "id": "2",
      "action": "update",
      "actor": {
        "type": "user"
      },
      "audit": {
        "timestamp": 1568677280
      }
    }
  ],
  "response_metadata": {
    "next_cursor": "hmV4dF9jcXJzb3I6MTU3OTg1NTC1jMWFFDGVmZGQwOTU="
  }
}
```

**JOLT Spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "list": {
        "*": {
          "extractedAt": "${now()}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Nifi Config**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to get unix epoch timestamp in miliseconds, applying a **`toNumber()`** conversion to the **`$now()`**, which's a date object, will resolve the issue such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "list": {
        "*": {
          "extractedAt": "${now():toNumber():divide(1000)}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

- **`JoltTransformJSON`** processor in Apache Nifi( current latest version is *`1.21.0`* ) supports ***`now()`*** as
  [documented](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#now)
- **`Jolt Transform DSL`** property which should be ***`chain`***, unlike to the current one, as you already define the operation type within the *Specification*

Comment: It is adding as it is and not the actual current time.

"extractedAt" : "${now():toNumber()}"

Comment: Jolt doesnt support now() it seems

Comment: Hi @user1578872 JoltTransformJSON processor in Apache Nifi supports `now()` as stated in the [document](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#now) . Btw, I have divided the result by 1000

Comment: Nifi throws error for the same spec above.
com.bazaarvoice.jolt.exception.SpecException: OVERWRITR expected a spec of Map type, got ArrayList

Comment: What's your NiFi version @user1578872 ? Mine is `1.19.1`

Comment: I am using nifi-1.20.0

Comment: @user1578872 The issue is due to the `Jolt Transform DSL` property which should be `chain` as you already define the operation type within the **Spec**